# Multiple Comment Forms on One Page in One Template - Django

Tags: django, forms, comments

I have researched this and many answers out there touch on it (formsets, prefixes, etc), but none is exactly what I'm after...

I have an application that allows users to post cards to a board and each card can have zero or more comments. I have the database relationships set up so if I manually add board, card, or comment objects I can display them in the template just fine.

The card form is also working, so this is not an issue. But now I want to display a comment `textarea` with a `click` event (which I have working with jQuery). The problem is, the form is not displaying the field. Here is the form code:

```
class AddCommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['message']

    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control comment-input'
                'name': 'message',
                'placeholder': 'Comment away...'
            }
        ),
        required=False,
    )
```

Right off the bat, there is a problem in that when Django renders a form, it uses an `id`. In this case, it ends up being `id_message` or `message` (depending on whether I specify in form class). Of course, in HTML, this is no good. I confirmed this in the shell:

```
>>> import django; import project
>>> from apps.board.forms import AddCommentForm
>>> comment_form = AddCommentForm(); print(comment_form)
<tr><th><label for="message">Message:</label></th><td><textarea class="form-control comment-input" cols="40" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Comment away..." rows="10">
</textarea></td></tr>
```

So I thought of using [`formsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/) but it seems not quite right, because as I understand them, they are for several forms inside one `form` tag. My case is different, in that each card has zero or more comments and the flow of the HTML dictates that there should be several `form` elements.

Another challenge is that I need to have two views: one to process the cards and one to process each comment. I'm currently using different action values to accomplish this and it seems to work.

It seems like my use case is not so strange, and I can think of several cases where this kind of situation would occur: Twitter replies, comments on blog posts, etc. I just can't get Django to work with this.

I should also note that I can manually make this work with this:

```
<label>
    <textarea class="form-control comment-input" name="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</label>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a view segment:

```
class AddCommentView(View):

    model = Comment
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    template_name = 'somedir/template.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):

        comment_form = self.form_class()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'comment_form': comment_form
        })
```

If the form is working (from snippet above and shell test), I would expect this to show it on the page.

The URLConf is here:

`url(r'^comment/add/$', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment_view'),`

In writing this out, I see a confusing piece. My URL for the view is `/comment/add/` but I want the form to be rendered at `/dashboard/`. The problem is that there is another view at that URL already.

If I build the form without Django forms, then post data to `/comment/add/` the comment is created and saved in the database. So I guess I'm still trying to figure out how to use two views in one template with multiple forms. @Daniel Roseman points out the use of `prefix` and I guess this is worth exploring more.

**UPDATE 2**

So I got this to work using prefixes by removing the URL for that view and combining the views into one view. Two forms, one view, one template. But...

The source still shows replicate `id`s. I ended up not putting the `id` in the form attribute list. Since this is invalid HTML, what is best way to get around this?

In my view:

```
card_model = Card
comment_model = Comment

card_form_class = AddCardForm
comment_form_class = AddCommentForm
. . .
@method_decorator(login_required)
def get(self, request):

    card_form = self.card_form_class(prefix='card')
    comment_form = self.comment_form_class(prefix='comment')
    . . .
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have found a solution to this problem. To instantiate the form, you need to add `auto_id=False` to prevent multiple, replicate `id`s:

`comment_form = self.comment_form_class(prefix='comment', auto_id=False)`

Comment: I'm confused, you said the form is not being rendered, then you said it's rendering it with `id_message`. Which is it? Also, what's the problem you have with it having an id of id_message?

Comment: Well, couple things... I didn't say it was rendered with that `id`. I said ends up being... I know what Django does because I use its forms elsewhere. Second, I confirmed this with testing in the shell. I will add that to the question for clarity. The problem with `id`s is that in HTML you can only have one `id`, so the form would render with the same `id` in multiple `form`s.

Comment: let's see your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the Django form `prefix` was partially correct (thanks @ Daniel Roseman), the assertion that it doesn't matter how many form elements I have is not quite correct. It does matter, because by default the prefix was meant to be used in one form (as it creates multiple replicate `id`s). To use it in multiple forms, you also need `auto_id=False`. This prevents the id from being generated by the Django form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) parameter when instantiating your forms to give them non-conflicting ids.

Comment: The references says: "You can put several Django forms inside one `<form>` tag. To give each Form its own namespace, use the prefix keyword argument[...]" Will this work with multiple `form`s? I ask because I played around with prefixes a bit to no avail. There are several posts out there on the topic.

Comment: It makes no difference at all how many `<form>` tags you use. If you're having trouble, you should show the code you have tried and the errors you got.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I'm updating the question with some more code. Thanks.

Comment: So I got this to work using prefixes but the source still shows replicate `id`s. I ended up not putting the id in the form attribute list. Since this is invalid HTML, what is best way to get around this?